# Why am I getting HTTP_CODE 0 from curl?

Tags: php, http, curl

I have been using curl with PHP for a while. Today I've been trying to fetch http://www.webhostingstuff.com/category/Best-Hosting.html and I keep getting http code 0, which is new to me.

I set the headers

```
$s->headers = array(
                    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1",
                    "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
                    "Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5",
                    "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
                    "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
                    "Keep-Alive: 115",
                    "Connection: keep-alive",
                    "Referer: https://google.com"
                    );
```

and I have a cookie file (which has nothing in it when the script finishes loading)

Here's the curl function

```
function fetch($url, $username='',  $data='', $proxy=''){


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

    if(isset($proxy)) {     
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, 'proxyadmin:parola');
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
    if(!empty($username)) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie/{$username}.txt");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie/{$username}.txt");
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);        
    if (is_array($data) && count($data)>0) {    
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);   
        $params = http_build_query($data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);  
    }


    if (is_array($this->headers) && count($this->headers)>0){   
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers);   
    }

    $this->result = curl_exec($ch);
    $curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $header_size = $curl_info["header_size"];
    $this->headers = substr($this->result, 0, $header_size);
    $this->http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $this->error = curl_error($ch);

    curl_close($ch);    

}
```

I've also tried to execute via SSH from a different server(in case it's IP blocked)

```
[brian@ip-184-168-22-244 ~]$ curl -url http://www.webhostingstuff.com/addcomments/5ite.html
Enter host password for user 'rl':
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
[brian@ip-184-168-22-244 ~]$
```

How might I resolve this?

Comment: better? Couldn't do it before due to low amount of points

Comment: Can you post a capture of the raw HTTP traffic? You can capture via wireshark.

Comment: `curl --url http://www.webhostingstuff.com/addcomments/` returns `<a href="/go/fix_errors.php">Click here to resolve error</a><br><br><br><br>String ID: hx6EvSPWWSZn` ... Not sure if that's what you're looking for. Curl does require the referer in the .htaccess to match, otherwise it'll redirect...

Comment: @SauliusAntanavicius How did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 9):

Your command

> curl -url http://www.webhostingstuff.com/addcomments/5ite.html

should have been:

> curl --url http://www.webhostingstuff.com/addcomments/5ite.html

cURL thinks you are specifying the -u option, which is used to specify a username, hence the error message you got. You need to specify --url (two dashes).

Hope that at least helps with the debugging.

Answer (score 8):

Statuscode 0 means the connection was closed (gracefully) before any output was returned.

I guess I'd start by figuring out whether you can connect to the machine at all. If you have access to the remote machine it will likely help debugging.

Comment: why curl_info['http_code'] 0 in vimeo at live site.
The same code return "200" at localhost but returns 0 at live.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the http code 0 was being returned because of a connection timeout. By adding

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
```

I was able to get rid of the error

Comment: How did you find out it was because of connection timeout?

Comment: why curl_info['http_code'] 0 in vimeo at live site. The same code return "200" at localhost but returns 0 at live.

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday I faced similar problem. I spent 2 hours on this issue. I was on RHEL system. The curl code had below block for authentication:

```
if($httpCode == 200) {
    $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
    $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
    return array(true, "Login successful. Please wait while you are redirected to home page.");
}else if($httpCode == 401){
    return array(false, "Login failure. Incorrect username  / password");
}
```

This code was being used for authentication. In lab environment it returned 200, but on production it returned 0.

Then I made a similar script (which used curl), and run if from command line like `php test3.php` . This run resulted in `200` status code.

Then out of curiosity I decided to turn off `SELinux` temporarily by running this command:

```
setenforce 0
```

And guess what this worked. You can then properly set context by running `setsebool httpd_can_network_connect on`

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This was exactly my problem.

Answer (score 1):

0 code means curl can't find the server you were looking for.
"yahoo.com/whatever" will return 404, while "yahoo.comwhatever" will return 0.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it was some internal server error? Right now it works:

```
> GET /category/Best-Hosting.html HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: HTTP_Request2/0.5.2 (http://pear.php.net/package/http_request2) PHP/5.2.12
> Host: www.webhostingstuff.com
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< date: Sun, 31 Jul 2011 10:57:43 GMT
< server: Apache
< last-modified: Sun, 31 Jul 2011 10:55:00 GMT
< content-encoding: gzip
< vary: Accept-Encoding
< transfer-encoding: chunked
< content-type: text/html
```

I use [HTTP_Request2](http://pear.php.net/package/http_request2) pear package as curl wrapper, the code:

```
$url = 'http://www.webhostingstuff.com/category/Best-Hosting.html';
$request = new HTTP_Request2 (
    $url,
    HTTP_Request2::METHOD_GET,
    array (
        'adapter'          => new HTTP_Request2_Adapter_Curl(),
        'ssl_verify_peer'  => false,
    )
);

$request->attach(new HTTP_Request2_Observer_Log('log.txt'));
$result = $request->send();
```

Comment: how would I go about installing this on my server? As im slightly confused about it

Comment: If you have pear installed then simply run `pear install HTTP_Request2`, otherwise download this package and it's dependencies and place to pear directory.

Comment: Ah, after a fairly long wait to get this installed, Curl error: connect() timed out!, Im guessing its same thing, the log doesnt say anything either which is rather strange

Comment: Hmm, what you get if you change adapter to socket one? `'adapter'          => new HTTP_Request2_Adapter_Curl()` Seems like something is wrong with your curl lib.

Comment: 'adapter' => new HTTP_Request2_Adapter_Curl() seems the same as the one you posted before? Thing is I can fetch any website just fine, however this website seems to not be working,thats the weird thing

Comment: Sorry, `'adapter' => new HTTP_Request2_Adapter_Socket()`.

Comment: Still seems like the same error,

Fatal error: Uncaught <table style="border: 1px" cellspacing="0"> <tr><td colspan="3" style="background: #ff9999"> <b>HTTP_Request2_ConnectionException</b>: Unable to connect to tcp://www.webhostingstuff.com:80. Error: Connection timed out in <b>/home/review/public_html/HTTP/Request2/Adapter/Socket.php</b>...

Comment: Can you ping webhostingstuff.com from your server? Seems like you should move this question to serverfault.

Comment: PING webhostingstuff.com (208.101.27.207) 56(84) bytes of data.

64 bytes from www.webhostingstuff.com (208.101.27.207): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=110 ms

64 bytes from www.webhostingstuff.com (208.101.27.207): icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=119 ms

64 bytes from www.webhostingstuff.com (208.101.27.207): icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=109 ms

64 bytes from www.webhostingstuff.com (208.101.27.207): icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=119 ms

There are plenty more lines of this, so server isn't banned :/