# Curl php connection to API working in my localhost but not in remote server

Tags: php, curl, localhost

I am programming a php page to connect to some API.
The page runs smoothly from my local host and works as expected, let’s say
http://localhost/sistema/token.php

I get the expected response from api

```json
{
"Estado":200,
"Mensaje":"OK",
"Fecha":"2023-06-27T12:23:43.4251433-05:00",
"Procesamiento":
  {
    "Token":"332323232323xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "FechaExpiracion":"2023-06-27T13:23:43-05:00"
  }
}
```

But when I run the same page on my remote server, let’s say
http://myremoteserver.com/sistema/token.php

I get nothing

And When I use `curl_getinfo($curl)` I get this response:

```php
Array
  Array ( 
  [url] => https://test.apiprovider.com:123/APICargaFactura/api/Authz/TokenAcceso 
  [content_type] => 
  [http_code] => 0 
  [header_size] => 0 
  [request_size] => 0 
  [filetime] => -1 
  [ssl_verify_result] => 0 
  [redirect_count] => 0 
  [total_time] => 1.001407 
  [namelookup_time] => 0.000695 
  [connect_time] => 0 
  [pretransfer_time] => 0 
  [size_upload] => 0 
  [size_download] => 0 
  [speed_download] => 0 
  [speed_upload] => 0 
  [download_content_length] => -1 
  [upload_content_length] => -1 
  [starttransfer_time] => 0 
  [redirect_time] => 0 
  [redirect_url] => 
  [primary_ip] => 
  [certinfo] => Array ( ) 
  [primary_port] => 0 
  [local_ip] => 
  [local_port] => 0 
  [http_version] => 0 
  [protocol] => 0 
  [ssl_verifyresult] => 0 
  [scheme] => 
  [appconnect_time_us] => 0 
  [connect_time_us] => 0 
  [namelookup_time_us] => 695 
  [pretransfer_time_us] => 0 
  [redirect_time_us] => 0 
  [starttransfer_time_us] => 0 
  [total_time_us] => 1001407 
 )
```

Again it’s the same code, I test on localhost and then upload to the remote server,

I checked the curl lib and that it is working fine on the remote serve. The api provider says that they haven’t had this issue before...

Here is the code

```
<?php 
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://test.com:85/test/test/Authz/TokenAcceso',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'pUsuario: jDoe',
        'pClave: querty'
        ),
    ));
    //response is a JSON
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    echo " the api response was: " .  $response;
?>
```

I tried to get a response from an API from a remote server as in my localhost...

Comment: Maybe outbound HTTP requests from your live server are blocked by a firewall rule?

Comment: the http_code = 0  is an indication that you are not getting a response. as @ADyson suggests it could be a firewall rule, or a PHP configuration issue, [causing a timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887104/why-am-i-getting-http-code-0-from-curl). You ought to get a 200  if the connection succeeds

Comment: If the target URL is really http instead of https the problem may be some security issue on your live server

Comment: Sure that target servers are listening on these ports 123 or 85? Sounds unusual for http based api...

Comment: add CURLOPT_VERBOSE and post the verbose log: ```$stderrh=tmpfile();
curl_setopt_array($curl,array(CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1,CURLOPT_STDERR=>$stderrh));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
/* https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76268 */
rewind($stderrh); 
$stderr=stream_get_contents($stderrh);
fclose($stderrh);
var_dump($stderr);
``` - the `[http_code] => 0` suggest an actual connectivity issue, which CURLOPT_VERBOSE should clarify

Comment: also before the curl_close(), add a `if(curl_errno($ch) !== CURLE_OK){var_dump("CURL ERROR",curl_errno($ch),curl_error($ch));}`